# Creating, adding and using a UDF in Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase

I have written a sample UDF to TRIM a string from a table in hive :

```
package anoop;


import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class DataTrim  extends UDF{

String trimmed;

public Text trim(Text incomingData){

    trimmed= incomingData.toString().trim();

    return new Text(trimmed);
}


}
```

I created a jar for this "trim_string.jar" and saved it to hive lib folder.
Now I ran following :

```
add jar '~/hive-1.2.1/lib/trim_string.jar';  (success)
```

Now i run

```
 create temporary function trimmed1 as 'anoop.DataTrim';
```

But i am getting following error:

```
FAILED: Class anoop.DataTrim does not implement UDF, GenericUDF, or UDAF
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from     org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask
```

can some please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hive UDF must contain function named `evaluate`. rename the function named `trim` to `evaluate`

> public Text evaluate(Text incomingData)

**Note**: `String trimmed` is unnecessary as class member. You could move this to function as a local variable.

```
package anoop;


import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class DataTrim  extends UDF{

    public Text evaluate(Text incomingData){
        String trimmed;
        trimmed= incomingData.toString().trim();
        return new Text(trimmed);
    }


}
```

For more information refer this   [tutorial](http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/08/10/guide-to-writing-hive-udfs.html)

Comment: Hi, 
I tried with the above code , but now I am getting error: 
    FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments 'preciptotal': No matching method for class anoop.DataTrim with (string). Possible choices:..........................

The command that i used was: select trimmed1(skyconds) from hourlydata limit 10;

trimmed1 is the temporary function created. 
please help.

Comment: Hi. Seems i was not creating the JAR correctly. I recreated it using the above code. Now works perfectly.! thanks alot for help!